# Xamarin Android how to change the height of a spinner in a list view

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, spinner

I've got a spinner that appears in a listview.  I need to change the height of the spinner but for whatever reason the spinner's height won't change. Basically I need to increase the height to the height of the item in the listview. Below is the template for the Listview :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingRight="17dp"
        android:paddingLeft="17dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/DateTextView"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/DayOfWeekTextView"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:textSize="40px"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false"
            android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is how the spinner current appears :

[image]

Here's how I want it to appear

[image]

Adapter code for the spinner :

```
    public override Android.Views.View GetView(int position, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = statuses[position];
        var view = (convertView ?? activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem,
            parent,
            false));
        Android.Graphics.Color customColor = new Android.Graphics.Color();

        view.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(item.nStatusColor));
        var name = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1);
        //name.SetHeight(50);
        name.Text = item.nStatus;
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So versus doing this programmatically I started thinking about the Layout.  Then I realized the answer to setting the height is to add a RelativeLayout as a parent to the Spinner.  Then fill_parent.  See code below!

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` also if there is another object in the listview you can use `alignTop` and `alignBottom`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own drawable xml file and set it as Background Property of your Spinner. I will provide you an Example as soon as possible.

**Drawable Resource: saved as spinner.xml in the drawable directory**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FF327935" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:endColor="#FF6BCA70" android:startColor="#FF327935" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:endColor="#FF6BCA70" android:startColor="#FF327935" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FF327935" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:endColor="#FFCCCCCC" android:startColor="#FF333333" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_drag_hovered="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:endColor="#FF6BCA70" android:startColor="#FF327935" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:endColor="#FF6BCA70" android:startColor="#FF327935" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**Spinner:**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerMonths"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

**EDIT**

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="17dp"
android:paddingRight="17dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DateTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DayOfWeekTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT 2**

```
    public override Android.Views.View GetView(int position, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = statuses[position];
        var view = (convertView ?? activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem,
            parent,
            false));
        Android.Graphics.Color customColor = new Android.Graphics.Color();

        view.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(item.nStatusColor));
        var name = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1);
        //name.SetHeight(50);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams mParams = parent.getLayoutParams();
        mParams.height = 50;
        view.setLayoutParams(mParams);

        name.Text = item.nStatus;
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Yes. Put it in the drawable folder and point to it from the background Property of your Spinner.

Comment: I have: android:background="@drawable/spinner". You have to create a new XML Resource file named spinner.xml

Comment: That just makes a huge spinner because of the fixed height of 200dp.

Comment: New Update. With the custom background property you should be able to change the heigh.

Comment: That gets the size closer but if you notice I use this line in the adapter to set the background color : view.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(item.nStatusColor));

Comment: Also for the spinner itself I am using a baseadapter as well that has a text view for the spinner

Comment: Create two Spinner XML files with different colors and try to point programatically to the drawable file by R.drawable.spinnerRed or R.drawable.spinnerGreen

Comment: That won't work either.  I get the colors from a database call.  I think a better answer is if you look at the code for the GetView method maybe finding a way to set the size programmatically of the view.

Comment: Check out the Update 2

Comment: I did end up finding an answer as you'll see above but I will reward the bounty to you.  Alot of good effort in the answer but the site is making me wait 20 hours.